# SQL to limit the types of tables returned when connecting to Oracle Database in Power BI

Tags: oracle, powerbi, connection, powerbi-desktop

I have got a connection to an Oracle Database set up in Power BI.
This is working fine, apart from the fact it brings back 9500+ tables that start with "BIN".

Is there some SQL code I can put in the SQL statement section when connecting to the Oracle Database that limits the tables that it returns to ignore any table that begins with 'BIN'?

[image: Tables with bin]

Answer (score 0):

Tables starting with `BIN$` are tables that have been dropped but not purged and are in Oracle's "recycle bin".

The simplest method of not showing them is, if they are no longer required, to `PURGE` (delete) the tables from the recycle bin and then you will not see them as they will not exist.

You can use ([documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-82E62BDB-E886-4EF9-943C-C62D632E499B)):

- `PURGE TABLE BIN$0+xyzabcdefghi123` to get rid of an individual tables with that name (or you can use the original name of the table).
- `PURGE TABLESPACE tablespace_name USER username;` to get rid of all recycled tables in a table space belonging to a single user.
- `PURGE TABLESPACE tablespace_name;` to get rid of all recycled tables in a table space.
- `PURGE RECYCLEBIN;` to get rid of all of the current user's recycled tables.
- `PURGE DBA_RECYCLEBIN;` to get rid of everything in the recycle bin (assuming you have `SYSDBA` privileges).

Before purging tables you should make sure that they are really not required as you would need to restore from backups to bring them back.

Comment: Thanks for this however it seems I've only got read-only access to the database in Power BI. When I run that statement it comes back with an error message "Oracle: ORA-16000: database or pluggable database open for read-only access".

Comment: If you are sure that the recycled tables are not required then you can talk to the DBA and ask them to remove them. If you cannot do that then you will need to wait for someone to give a Power BI solution to hiding them (or search the internet for `power bi hide table` and see if you can find a solution yourself).